# Check smarty Syntax Error in Html

Tags: smarty

From php, Is there any way by which i can detect if there is any smarty syntax error in html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just fetch the Template and catch exceptions.

```
try {
    $template->fetch("test.tpl");
}
catch (Exception $e) {

}
```

You can place that in a function that returns whatever you need.